# R: How to read and rearrange multiple files

Tags: r

So what I want to do is to read multiple files into one tibble or data frame. My files all kind of look like below. For one ID there can be multiple files with different measurements

```
File_name:test01.csv
ID:1243
View:d
Unit:mm
length:555

File_name:test02.csv
ID:1243
View:v
Unit:mm
volume:111
width:333

File_name:  test03.csv
ID:1235
View:l
Unit:mm
length:666
height:444
width:222
```

What I want in the end is something like this

```
ID, Unit, Value,    Measure,    
1243,   mm, 555,    length
1243,   mm, 111,    volume
1243,   mm, 333,    width
1235,   mm, 666,    length  
1235,   mm, 444,    height
1235,   mm, 222,    width
```

What I have tried so far is, that I made a file list and read all files into one table

```
    csv_list %>%
  map_df(~ read.table(.,skip = 1, sep = ':')) -> data
```

or

```
    data_csv = ldply(xls_list, read.table, sep = ':', fill = T, header = F, skip = 1)
```

I get a long table with one file after the other, but I'm not sure how to go about rearranging it.

```
ID       :  1243
View     :  d
Unit     :  mm
length   :  555
ID       :  1243
View     :  v
Unit     :  mm
volume   :  111
width    :  333
ID       :  1235
View     :  l
Unit     :  mm
length   :  666
height   :  444
width    :  222
```

Another idea I head was to just read every file separately with a loop but this takes a really long time

```
#Complete Code
path = "D:/Scripts/R_projects/Pictures"
setwd(path)
xls_list = list.files(path, pattern = ".csv", full.names = T)

data_csv = ldply(xls_list, read.table, sep = ':', fill = T, header = F, skip = 1)

#or

xls_list %>%
  map_df(~ read.table(.,skip = 1, sep = ':')) -> data
glimpse(data)
```

Comment: CSV stands for "comma-separated values", but your files use ":" as a separator. Is that correct? Also, are there multiple chunks of data, each starting with "File_name", in each/some files, or do those chunks above represent different files?

Comment: That's sadly correct. It's not really a .csv file but they where saved as such. And they are seperate files., so test01 is a file, test02 is a file etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want something like the following, where I use readr's `read_delim` in `map_df` to read in and combine the files, and then tidyr's `spread` to rearrange the data to something tha makes sense:

```r
library(tidyverse)

map_df(list.files(pattern = "csv$"),
       read_delim,
       delim = ":",
       col_names = F,
       trim_ws = T,
       .id = "df" # <- necessary for spread
       ) %>%
    spread(X1, X2, convert = T) # <- spread and coerce
```

Which returns:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 9
  df    File_name  height    ID length Unit  View  volume width
  <chr> <chr>       <int> <int>  <int> <chr> <chr>  <int> <int>
1 1     test01.csv     NA  1243    555 mm    d         NA    NA
2 2     test02.csv     NA  1243     NA mm    v        111   333
3 3     test03.csv    444  1235    666 mm    l         NA   222
```

If you need it in tidy (long) format just add `gather`:

```r
map_df(list.files(pattern = "csv$"),
       read_delim,
       delim = ":",
       col_names = F,
       trim_ws = T,
       .id = "df"
       ) %>%
    spread(X1, X2, convert = T) %>% 
    gather(measure_name, measure_val, height, length, volume, width)
```

Which returns:

```r
# A tibble: 12 x 7
   df    File_name     ID Unit  View  measure_name measure_val
   <chr> <chr>      <int> <chr> <chr> <chr>              <int>
 1 1     test01.csv  1243 mm    d     height                NA
 2 2     test02.csv  1243 mm    v     height                NA
 3 3     test03.csv  1235 mm    l     height               444
 4 1     test01.csv  1243 mm    d     length               555
 5 2     test02.csv  1243 mm    v     length                NA
 6 3     test03.csv  1235 mm    l     length               666
 7 1     test01.csv  1243 mm    d     volume                NA
 8 2     test02.csv  1243 mm    v     volume               111
 9 3     test03.csv  1235 mm    l     volume                NA
10 1     test01.csv  1243 mm    d     width                 NA
11 2     test02.csv  1243 mm    v     width                333
12 3     test03.csv  1235 mm    l     width                222
```